# Visual Studio 2015 Unsupported Devices

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have a new set up visual studio 2015 (updated) in a new laptop and I am having a problem with my project from an old laptop. I don't know why my device and 2 emulators are listed on Unsupported Devices in this new set up visual studio.

Minimum Android version is set to android 4.1 jelly bean
target is set to compile using SDK version
Compile using nougat 7.0/also tried to marshmallow 6.0

[image]

I have my phone nougat 7.0 and 2 emulators 6.0 but I don't know why from my copied project from old laptop says API Level is less than the minimum Android version defined in the manifest file

[image]

Already tried to delete bin and obj folders. Tried to set min, target and compile with other combinations but no luck to solve this issue.

What can I do with this old project in my new VS 2015 set up? My new projects don't have a problem at all.

Comment: What about restart?

Comment: Still no luck for that since i'm opening it everyday to test.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, there's a "minimun android version" dropdown under the *Android Manifest* tab in the project settings. Changing it **there** made my emulator pop up again. Got the idea by reading this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

**Edit:** I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community

Comment: It didn't solve the problem in any way. I tried everything I can including that but failed. Anyway thanks for bringing this up again. I have found solution in here.

Comment: Glad you found your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this. I have found out that it is because of API 24 and up from my SDK manager. I deleted those API and voila ! Unsupported devices are gone and back to normal . I don't know if it is because of the project built from another laptop only having API 23 below and when I transferred it to a my laptop with Nougat and Oreo API, unsupported devices happened. Hope it give helps to other coders.